# WebStorm - Node.JS project

Tags: debugging, webstorm

In WebStorm - NodeJS project - index.ejs which consists of both HTML and JavaScript Code, the Debugger does not allow me to set breakpoints in the embedded JavaScript in it i.e., index.ejs .
Pls let me know how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

it's not currently supported - please vote for [WEB-1173](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1173) and [WEB-8333](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8333)